# LSUIPresentationMode no longer works in Yosemite

Tags: macos

I've always set `LSUIPresentationMode` to 4 in iTerm and Firefox to hide the annoying unnecessary menu bar taking up precious vertical space on my macbook.

If I needed the menu, I could just move my mouse to the top of the screen, and it would appear. The rest of the time that space was used by the terminal and the browser.

After an upgrade to Yosemite this features no longer works. Most of the time setting this option to 4 or 3 (hide completely) does nothing. Sometimes it crashes the app. Sometimes the menu is hidden but the empty space is not occupied, so there's a long line on top.

This is really annoying. I submitted a bug report to Apple during the beta test - no response.

Running apps full screen is not an option. Unlike Linux implementation, OS X's full screen is not usable for me. You have to switch between spaces, you can't open other windows on top, etc.

So does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since El Capitan you can now hide the menubar via System Preferences > Appearance.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

You can run

```
lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox ApplicationType=UIElement
```

but you have to run it every time you open Firefox, it removes the menu bar completely, and it removes Firefox from the Dock. Commands like `lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox PresentationMode=Suppressed` or `lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox UIPresentationMode=4` didn't seem to work.

(You can make the full screen mode actually usable in iTerm 2 by unchecking "Use Lion-style Fullscreen windows" and setting "Profiles > Window > Style" to "Fullscreen". Skim, Sequential, Movist, and Emacs also have an option to use a custom implementation for full screen windows.)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the iTerm tip. The full screen mode is now perfect. However running the lsappinfo command for Firefox gives me "err=-50"

Comment: Ok, I managed to run the UIElement command (had to launch Firefox first), but it only hides it from the Dock and the alt-tab menu. The top bar is still there.